# Aplanar matriz en R

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaría conseguir un dataframe con el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, los nombres únicos serían los identificadores por filas y los eventos únicos los identificadores por columnas, de tal forma que pueda ver, por ejemplo, cuántas veces ha hecho name1 el evento event1 sin cambiar de fila.

Estoy intentando recorrer el dataframe 1 con bucles for para construir el dataframe 2 pero no acabo de verlo.

¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez de las formas más sencillas de resolverlo es usar `dplyr/magrittr` o lo que es lo mismo el metapaquete `tidyverse`:

```
df <- data.frame(NAMES=c("name1", "name1", "name1", "name2", "name2", "name3"),
                 EVENTS=c("event1", "event2", "event3", "event2", "event1", "event3"),
                 N=c(3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 4))

library(tidyverse)

# Expandimos los eventos en columnas y rellenamos con 0
df %>%
    spread(key=EVENTS, value=N, fill = 0) 

  NAMES event1 event2 event3
1 name1      3      6      8
2 name2      1      2      0
3 name3      0      0      4
```

Eventualmente, si lo quisieras resolver con R base, es bastante simple también, usando [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html) aunque un poco menos claro de entender:

```
dfnew <- reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar="NAMES", timevar="EVENTS")    
dfnew[,-1][is.na(dfnew[, -1])] <- 0
```

- Con `reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar="NAMES", timevar="EVENTS")` indicamos que vamos a pasar de un formato largo a ancho (`direction = "wide"`). La columna que no expandiremos será `idvar="NAMES"` y la que se expandirá será `timevar="EVENTS"`.
- `dfnew[,-1][is.na(dfnew[, -1])] <- 0` remplaza los `NA` solo en las columnas de los eventos.

Comment: El argumento `fill` de `spread()` especifica el valor de relleno, que por defecto es NA. Entonces: `df %>% spread(EVENTS, N, fill = 0)`

Comment: Glorioso dato @mpaladino, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es el típico caso de las funciones melt y dcast (son inversas entre si) de la librería reshape2 (https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/).
En tu caso tienes que usar dcast, si tu dataframe se llama df:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(NAMES=c("n1","n1","n1","n2","n2","n3"),EVENTS=c("ev1","ev2","ev3","ev2","ev1","ev3"),N=c(3,6,8,2,1,4))
df2 <- dcast(df,NAMES ~ EVENTS, value.var = "N")
df2[is.na(df2)]<-0
```